# How to get the index of an object in Ballerina Array?

Tags: arrays, ballerina

How can I get the index of an object in a Ballerina array in an efficient way?
Is there any inbuilt function to do that?

Comment: I think you need to come up with a suitable searching algorithm for your usecase. We don’t have any inbuilt methods at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Ballerina now offers the [`indexOf`](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/blob/56c946b28cb7617974f4c290970fcd67505ab0ac/langlib/lang.array/src/main/java/org/ballerinalang/langlib/array/IndexOf.java#L47) and [`lastIndexOf`](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/blob/56c946b28cb7617974f4c290970fcd67505ab0ac/langlib/lang.array/src/main/java/org/ballerinalang/langlib/array/LastIndexOf.java#L45) methods, as of language specification 2020R1.

They return the first and last indices for items that satisfy the equality, respectively. We get `()` if the value is not found.

```golang
import ballerina/io;


public function main() {
    string[*] example = ["this", "is", "an", "example", "for", "example"];

    // indexOf returns the index of the first element found
    io:println(example.indexOf("example")); // 3

    // The second parameter can be used to change the starting point
    // Here, "is" appears at index 1, so the return value is ()
    io:println(example.indexOf("is", 3) == ()); // true

    // lastIndexOf will find the last element instead
    // (the implementation will do the lookup backwards)
    io:println(example.lastIndexOf("example")); // 5

    // Here the second parameter is where to stop looking
    // (or where to start searching backwards from)
    io:println(example.lastIndexOf("example", 4)); // 3
}
```

**[Run it in the Ballerina Playground](https://play.ballerina.io/?gist=8e6c2a7268279c936c5b5dfd050a04e1&file=play.bal)**

The description of these and other functions can be found [in the spec](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-spec/blob/master/lang/lib/array.bal).