# ballerina - Check if a value exists in an Array

Tags: arrays, list, arraylist, ballerina

Is there any inbuilt function in ballerina to check if a value exists in an array?

I tried a simple function which iterate through a string array and checking the whether the value is present.

```
function isContain(string[] array1,string id) returns (boolean) {
    int i=0;
    int checker=-0;
    while (i<lengthof (array1)) {
        if(array1[i]==id){
            checker = 1;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (checker == 1){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is a duplicate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201810/how-to-get-the-index-of-an-object-in-ballerina-array

Comment: Your algorithem will perform at O(N) at worst case.  If your string array is large, then I would recommend using the binary search algorithem which will perform at O(log N)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the index of an object in Ballerina Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201810/how-to-get-the-index-of-an-object-in-ballerina-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [indexOf()](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.array/0.0.0/functions#indexOf) to solve this. You can write the `isContain` function as follows

```
function isContain(string[] array1, string id) returns boolean {
    return array1.indexOf(id) != ();
}
```